# Reading tiff raster data

Tags: java, tiff, gdal

I'm reading a 2048X2048 pixels tiff file using the method below:

```
private static int[][] convertTo2DWithoutUsingGetRGB(BufferedImage image) {

    final short[] pixels = ((DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    int[][] data = new int[2048][2048];

    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int blockSize = 2048;
    for (int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++) {
        data[col][row] = pixels[i];
        row++;
        if (row == blockSize) {
            col++;
            row = 0;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

But I keep getting negative values on my array, if I use gdal with python, for example:

```
import gdal # Tiff Image Read

def getArrayFromImage(fileName):
    img = gdal.Open(fileName)
    return img.ReadAsArray().astype(int)
```

I get only positive values. In the java method above is there a treatment needed in the raw value to be a valid pixel for the tiff image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but solved the issue by adding 65536 to the value if it is negative.

```
int j = pixels[i];
if (j < 0) {
    j += 65536;
}
data[col][row] = j;
```